# Herman's paper on the smoothness of conjugacy for irrational circle rotation in english

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Can someone help me and tell me where to find the Herman's paper in english (or proof of his theorem) [Sur la conjugaison différentiable des difféomorphismes du cercle à des rotations](https://eudml.org/doc/103958)?

Comment: Have you looked in An Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems by Katok and Hasselblatt? I don't know for sure that it's there, but it's a likely bet.

Comment: @Anthony No, it is not there.

Comment: Yoccoz generalized Herman's result, maybe his article is in English?
I recall also that Katznelson and Ornstein dealt with the non-Liouvillian case, and I'm pretty sure their paper is in English.

Comment: Yoccoz did many things, but also in French, I think...

Answer (score 2):

Here are scans of copies of 3 manuscripts of Herman:  https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~cheritat/Herman/herman.html